# PHP Crawler going in Infinite Loop

Tags: php, database, loops, foreach, web-crawler

This is the whole crawler code that I am trying to build. This code is a single domain crawler. But it has a big problem, when I checked the database it was saving some of the links again and again, which creates an infinite loop. I want to solve this problem without using my database because checking each link for a presence in my database will make this crawler slow. How can I do that? + If you have any suggestions to make it faster?

```
<?php

include_once('ganon.php');

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
function gethost($link)
{
    $link = trim($link, '/');
    if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $link)) 
    {
        $link = 'http://' . $link;
    }
    $urlParts = parse_url($link);
    $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);
    return $domain;
}

function store($raw, $link)
{
    $html = str_get_dom($raw);
    $title = $html('title', 0)->getPlainText();

    $con = @mysqli_connect('somehost', 'someuser', 'somepassword', 'somedatabase');
    if (!$con) 
    {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `somedatabase`.`sometable` (`title`, `url`) VALUES ('$title', '$link');";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    mysqli_close($con);
    echo $title."<br>";
}

function crawl_save_crawl($target)
{
    $curl = curl_init($target);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl)) 
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl); 


    $dom = str_get_dom($result);
    foreach($dom('a') as $element)
    {
        $href = $element->href;
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) 
        {
            $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
            if (extension_loaded('http')) 
            {
                $href = http_build_url("http://www.".gethost($target), array('path' => $path));
            }   
            else 
            {
                $parts = parse_url("http://www.".gethost($target));
                $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) 
                {
                    $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                }   
                $href .= $parts['host'];
                if (isset($parts['port'])) 
                {
                    $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                }
                $href .= dirname($parts['path'], 1).$path;
            }   
        }
        if (gethost($target) == gethost($href))
        {
            crawl_save_crawl($href);
        }
    }
    store($result, $target);        
}

$url=$_GET['u'];
crawl_save_crawl($url); 

?>
```

Comment: The question is a bit broad - could you specify/explain better?

Comment: the problem is for ex:- i was trying to crawl google.com then what i saw in my database it has perfectly crawled google.com after that it started to crawl the first link. Let first link was google.com/signin . on this signin in page again there was a link www.google.com so it again started to crawl google.com where it found the signin link again.....
hence an infinite loop @rammelmueller

Comment: One thing which will make this quicker is to connect to the database once (before the call to `crawl_save_crawl()`) and pass the connection round.

Answer (score 0):

In your `crawl_save_crawl()` function, you could store the links you've already visited and therefore stop the code going back to them.  Using a static variable isn't ideal, but in such a limited piece of code it serves the purpose it was intended for (to hold it's value across calls).

This doesn't stop it searching things other pages have searched, but stops it looping in itself.

```
function crawl_save_crawl($target)
{
    static $alreadyDone = null;
    if ( $alreadyDone == null ) {
        $alreadyDone = [$target];
    }
```

In the first loop, this will add the current reference in as this would previously have caused it to be missing.

Then before you call the same routing, you can test if it's already been checked...

```
$visit = trim(str_replace(["http://","https://"], "", $href), '/');
if (in_array($visit, $alreadyDone) === false &&
    gethost($target) == gethost($href))
{
    $alreadyDone[] = $visit;
    crawl_save_crawl($href);
}
```

This may still look as though it's visiting the same page, but as your logic sometimes creates a href with 'www.' at the start, this may be different than without it.  So when ccrawling stackoverflow, this means there is stackoverflow.com and www.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: how can i get the http or https removed url

Comment: Don't worry about that, just check that the rest is working first.

Comment: this did not work still going in a loop with no error

Comment: Can you let me know the URL your trying?

Comment: still didnt worked... it saved "...https://...www...stackoverflow.com" 4 times in database. i checked it with this query SELECT * FROM `jdindex` where url="...https://....www....stackoverflow.com" [i added dots because https and www was not showing in comment]

Comment: Do you delete all of the previous rows when you run this each time?

Comment: I've just tried it and the reason I had 3 versions of stackoverflow.com - `http://stackoverflow.com`, `https://stackoverflow.com` and `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, which are all different.

Comment: did your code worked good or not? in my case i just want to crawl any one of them and reject all others..